# Migration php to nodejs - Handled Session in Client Side

Tags: javascript, node.js, session

i develop web system in PHP and now i'm very excited with NODEJS.

Even though it is not a good practice, in my view, many times do that:

If the user is not logged in, them redirect.

```
<?php

  session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['login']) || 4 !== (integer)$_SESSION['id_perfil_sistema']){
        header("Location: /vault/");
    }

?>
```

And other times I get the session data to customize the page according to the logged User

`<li style="background-color:#ddd;">
      <a style="color:blue;" href="#">
             <?php echo ucwords($_SESSION['nomeusuario']); ?>
      </a>
</li>`

```
<input type="hidden" name="theOrigin" value="<?=$_SESSION['origin'];?>" />

<script type="text/javascript">
     var x = <?php echo $_SESSION['session_variable']; ?>;
</script>
```

I have learned to create session in nodejs. =)

What best way to get session nodejs in javascript ?

I'm using nodejs and express.

kind regards

Comment: did this help at all?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get session from any request object, once you have included the express session middleware (https://github.com/expressjs/session)

For example redirecting all non-logged in users to '/login', can be written as express middleware on each request like this:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if(!req.session.login){
      res.redirect("/login");
      return;
  }
  next();
});
```

and to add session to markup (assumes using Jade or other express templating middleware)

JS

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.render('index', { nomeusuario: req.session.nomeusuario });
});
```

Jade (example)

```
html
  body
    h1= nomeusuario
```

Note: Code not tested, just an example

Comment: Great answer, @Ollieh!  
@felipe-muner, I recommend you jade templating for: code readability, coding productivity, child-to-parent layout usage (you define layout filling in extenders) and [more](http://vstark.net/2014/10/18/jade-vs-html/).

A plus: you can use [config package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) to define resource paths (using CDN? Use it!) and general application configuration.